# Out write rate into a string - Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and** > 'double'

Tags: c#

it is such that I must have written price in a string to be displayed to users.

right now will give this error is

> **Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and**
>   **'double'**

It is such that I must have given my users something off of it as they cost if they have chosen the right time.

```
Double moms = 1.30;
ButtonPay.Text = "Buy Membership - DKK " + (prisenMedlemskab / moms).ToString("F2") + ",- Kr";
```

the reason I have done this is the very reason that I do this on the page.

Comment: `prisenMedlemskab` looks like a `string` and that's why you get this error. Have you ever try it to double first or some numeric value?

Comment: What is the `prisenMedlemskab` exactly by the way?

Comment: @SonerGönül price membership it is something that comes out from the database, and sorry I forgot to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prisenMedlemskab` seems to be a string, so you cannot divide it for a number. Try to convert as follows

```
Double moms = 1.30;
ButtonPay.Text = "Buy Membership - DKK " + (Convert.ToDouble(prisenMedlemskab) / moms).ToString("F2") + ",- Kr";
```

By the way is safer to convert `prisenMedlemskab` before use it directly so you can check if converted value is a legal one (so if `prisenMedlemskab` has an actual convertable value)

Comment: Was it really just so that I skullle do it ... but it works should and thanks for your help .. I hope you will give me a +1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you, `prisenMedlemskab` is a string and not an integer
You have to parse it.

e.g.

```
double prisenMedlemskabDouble = double.Parse(prisenMedlemskab);
```

And then do

```
ButtonPay.Text = "Buy Membership - DKK " + (prisenMedlemskabDouble / moms).ToString("F2") + ",- Kr";
```